# How to work with mobile chrome and testing app by Appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I'm automationg mobile application, but in some cases I need to click on link and check that approproate link was opened by browser. For example link Terms of Service on SignUP page of my application.So the question is -HOW to switch between testing app and browser.Here is my code

```
    File apk = new File("src/test/resources/myapp.apk");   
    DesiredCapabilities AppCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    DesiredCapabilities chromeCapabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();
    AppCapabilities.setCapability("app", apk.getAbsolutePath());     
    AppCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    AppCapabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");

    AppCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "MyDevice");
    AppCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.3");
    //capabilities.setCapability(key, value);    
    AppCapabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 400); 
    androidDriver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), AppCapabilities);
```

but something like adroidDriver.getCurrentURL() doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few capabilities.

Please look at the server flag and capabilities for anything related to "Chrome" http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#server-flags

And then please take a look at the documentation for automation using ChromeDriver with Appium.
http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#mobile-chrome-on-emulator-or-real-device

Comment: Do you mean that I have to use additional webdriver(chrome)for checking everything related browser side?

Comment: I misread your question. You're asking about changing from Native to WebApp to make sure that what's on the screen is the link you just opened. I gave you an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. Just add one more appium node and define additional driver for mobile browser